# Sound in Ubuntu 10.04 guest VM in a Ubuntu 8.04 host is "slow". How to fix it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, virtualbox, pulse-audio

When I try to execute sound in Rythmbox, it's "slow". Not only Rythmbox, but system sounds are strange too (they look like they are "slow").

I've tried [a workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341984) but without success. It seens [a ticket it's already opened for it](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4605), but I can't see a fix... Are other workarounds possible?

Anyone knows what this could be? I'm using Virtual Box 3.2.4 r62467.

### Host Config:

---

Ubuntu 8.04

Kernel 2.6.24-19-386

Memory 3,0gb

Intel Core 2 Quad @2.66GHz

Free Space: 256,8GiB

### VM (Guest) config:

---

**General**
Name: Development
OS Type: Ubuntu

**System**
Base Memory: 1112 MB
Processor(s): 1
Boot Order: Floppy, CD/DVD-ROM, Hard Disk, Network
VT-x/AMD-V: Enabled
Nested Paging: Enabled

**Display**
Video Memory: 64 MB
3D Acceleration: Disabled
2D Video Acceleration: Disabled
Remote Display Server:Disabled

**Storage**
IDE Controller
IDE Secondary Master (CD/DVD): Empty
SATA Controller
SATA Port 0: Development.vdi (Normal, 12,45 GB)

**Audio**
Host Driver: PulseAudio
Controller: ICH AC97

**Network**
Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (NAT)

**Serial Ports**
Disabled

**USB**
Device Filters: 0 (0 active)

**Shared Folders**
Shared Folders: 1

Comment: Just to clarify, “slow” refers to sound distortion (low pitch and clock speed), not dropped samples.

Comment: Ah, my clarification was off the mark. The workaround and the ticket weren't in fact relevant. Congratulations to the OP for solving the problem themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My co-worker solved it!!!

We were reading [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843012), when we came across an interesting section:

> If you have an HDA-Intel device try
>   turning up the PCM slider in the
>   volume control. If PCM is set to 0 it
>   makes the sound scratchy for some of
>   those devices.
>
> Otherwise if your sound is scratchy or
>   stuttering you can edit these lines in
>   the file /etc/pulse/daemon.conf to
>   look like this Code:
>
> **default-fragments = 5**
>
> **default-fragment-size =25**
>
> There are also some sound cards/chips
>   that can only be fixed with an ALSA
>   upgrade so you may want to consider
>   that if this does not work for you.

These are the words I couldn't think of (english isn't my native language): **if your sound is scratchy or stuttering**.

Then we thought: what about trying to mess up with this configuration? So we started changing these values in an arbitrary manner, when we realized the sound was changing, we came up with these values:

```
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
```

(note that default-fragment-size is called **default-fragment-size-msec** instead).

...and now everything works. Tested in two different machines, two different vms, created from scratch and some that were already created that had this fix.

Comment: You should simply disable pulse in a VM or install OSS. But yeah this also works. :P

Comment: I prefer this approach, since I have an old host and can't upgrade and I don't want to mess up with other drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The bug report and its workaround are plausible. Maybe the module parameters need to be adjusted for the exact sound driver your guest uses. You should try looking in dmesg if the ac97 clock speed varies across guest runs. If this is the same problem, but the solution needs to be adjusted, use lsmod and modinfo to find the correct parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution, posting to add more cross-references:

> Appears to be a common problem for many Linux guests, regardless of host operating system.
>
> A workaround/fix was identified by someone using Ubuntu 9.04 was to stick the following into /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf (might need a .conf extension, or might not):

```
options snd-intel8x0 ac97_clock=48000
options snd slots=snd-intel8x0
# CvwD.FAMlirE10w6:82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
alias snd-card-0 snd-intel8x0
```

More info @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/324889/multimedia-running-very-slow-weird-in-virtualbox